# GridView with radio button Column

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I'm trying to make a gridView with a radio button as first column.

I'm using

```
        DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemCheckEdit m_repositoryItemCheckEdit
```

as the frist's column repository edit.

Properties:

```
          m_repositoryItemCheckEdit.CheckStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.CheckStyles.Radio;
```

as the editor for the first Column.

I'm trying to create an ordinary radio button list :
 1) At least one option is selected
 2) At most one option is selected

For the second rule i've used the CheckedChange event to obtain the behavior:

```
     void m_repositoryItemCheckEdit_CheckedChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedRow = m_gridView.GetSelectedRows()[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < m_gridView.RowCount; i++)
        {
            //change the checked state to false for all rows except the selected one
            if (i != selectedRow)
            {
                MyRecord o = m_gridView.GetRow(i) as MyRecord;
                o.Checked = false;
            }
        }
        m_gridView.RefreshData();

    }
```

I can't figure out how to obtain the first rule.

Can you help me please?

EDIT:

MyRecord is :

```
      public class MyRecord
{
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MyRecord(bool i_checked, string name)
    {
        Checked = i_checked;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think to create a radio button list you need to use RepositoryItemRadioGroup.

Answer (score 0):

To implement the first rule, handle the [GridView.ShowingEditor](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_ShowingEditortopic) event. This event allows you to disable a certain cell accoring to an arbitrare rule. Within the event handler verify that the [GridView.FocusedColumn](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_FocusedColumntopic) equals your checkbox column. Then look through rows, and if the focused row is the only checked row, do not show the editor by setting the e.Cancel property to true.